# Yii2 ActiveRecord saves null values instead of real values

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I'm starting with Yii2 and want to save something to my database.
this is my model:

```
class Course extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $name;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name'], 'integer']
        ];
    }
}
```

and I call it like this:

```
$Course = new Course();
$Course->name = 44;
$Course->save();
```

This is a simple code but it insert null in my database. my table just has a name column as int.
What is the solution?
I have read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41766286/yii2-model-saves-null-values) question but his problem is not the same as me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `name` is the real column name from your database you need to remove

```
public $name;
```

from your ActiveRecord class. You can not have model properties of the same name as the database columns declared in the class because ActiveRecord won't work.

Comment: So how can I access name property?

Comment: Like you did before `->name` - but do not declare it.